# Does smtpfailedrecipientsexception work for CC and BCC

Tags: asp.net, system.net.mail

I'm trying to get my head round the System.Net.Mail class but I'm having trouble finding decent documentation.

First query - Say I have an email with a CC and a BCC email, do I need to catch SmtpFailedRecipientsException instead of SmtpFailedRecipientException (note the singlular Recipient) or is it intended for sending to multiple TO recipients?

Second query - when I iterate through the exceptions using the method below, will the inner exceptions relate to the email addresses that have failed, such as the BCC but not the TO or CC. If this is the case will the resend then go to all 3 again?

```
    static void CheckExceptionAndResend(SmtpFailedRecipientsException ex, SmtpClient client, MailMessage message)
    {
        var status = ex.StatusCode;

        for (int i = 0; i < ex.InnerExceptions.Length; i++)
        {
            if (status == SmtpStatusCode.MailboxBusy ||
                status == SmtpStatusCode.MailboxUnavailable ||
                status == SmtpStatusCode.TransactionFailed)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                client.Send(message);
            }
            else
            {
                // TODO: Log delivery failure
            }
        }
    }
```

All advice appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know and can't answer your 1st query but to answer the 2nd one, if you are not sending the message anywhere except in this method, I don't understand how the message will be sent again or twice to the recipients..

But if you are sending the message using the smtpclient instance before this method gets invoked because of an exception, then yes, the message gets delievered again to all 3 i.e. TO, BCC and CC, not just to the failed recipients..

Comment: Yes, there is a method that calls client.Send() then calls the method shown on SmtpFailedRecipientsException exception. You have answered the second part. It seems logical because the message is never 'rebuilt', just resent.

Comment: Also, it seems that exceptions will only be thrown for local email addresses, therefore, if I'm sending out emails to users rather than my own internal admin, no exception will be caught.

Comment: @dotnetnoob that is true if you are in intranet because your smtp client instance is initialized with the value of your intranet's smtp mailing host which can only detect failures of local mail addresses, not others..

Answer (score 0):

For your 1st query, have a look at the source code for [SmtpTransport.SendMail()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/net/System/Net/mail/SmtpTransport.cs.html#eb69bd2f50005459), which is called by [SmtpClient.Send()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/R/cca069628a6b9b57.html).  If only one recipient (regardless of To, CC, or BCC) is rejected, the resulting exception will be SmtpFailedRecipientException, but if more than one is rejected, it'll be SmtpFailedRecipientsException.  Inconveniently, I believe this means you'd need to try to catch both types.